# Vlookup 2 column index numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to look  in 2 index value, if there is no value present in that index, it should check the next index number and pop the value.

I tried these 2 formulas, its not working :

1. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'sheet1'!A:S,**19:20**,FALSE),"")`
2. `=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A5,'Sheet1'!A1:T92,19,0))),"Main", IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A5,'Sheet1'!A1:T92,20,0))),"Residual","Notfound"))`

Here i need to pop up S, in case if column S is blank take the value from Column T.

How do i tackle this.. ?

Comment: It's unclear on whether you want to return the actual values from either column S or T or display Main/Residual/Not found.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your first formula isn't:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'sheet1'!A:S,20,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A5,'sheet1'!A:S,19,FALSE))
```

while it is unclear what you really want... if you want `T` if `S` is empty then:

```
=IF(len(LOOKUP(A5,B:B,S:S)),LOOKUP(A5,B:B,S:S),LOOKUP(A5,B:B,T:T))
'looking in B:B and output S if its not empty else output T
```

if you want to output `S` if the searchstring is found else output `T` it would be something like:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(A5,S:S,X:X),LOOKUP(A5,T:T,X:X))
'change X:X to the column where the output values are stored in
```

but if you just need the "Main","Residual" and "Notfound" as output you may use something like:

```
=IF(MATCH(A5,S:S,0),"Main",IF(MATCH(A5,T:T,0),"Residual","Notfound"))
```

however... we need more information to give you a real answer :/